# Configuring IIS Client Certificate Mapping Authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis, ssl, x509certificate

I'm trying to configure IIS client cert mapping on IIS 8, Windows Server 2012. I don't see the configuration showing up in applicationHost.config, and the cert I'm trying to present isn't offered up as an option by my browser.

Here's what I've tried so far:

In IIS, I created a top-level site called "PackageManager":

[image]

SSL Settings are as follows:

[image]

Authentication: Enabled Anonymous:

[image]

In Configuration Editor, 
Section: `system.webServer/security/authentication/iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication`
From: `ApplicationHost.config <location path=’PackageManager’>`
I set the following:

[image]

I wanted `manyToOneMappings` so I could map the cert to my service account (a domain user):

[image]

Here I created 2 rules to match the Subject and Issuer CN's of the GoDaddy cert:

[image]

Then I generated a PowerShell script for all the above as follows:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location 'PackageManager' -filter "system.webServer/security/authentication/iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication" -name "enabled" -value "True"
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location 'PackageManager' -filter "system.webServer/security/authentication/iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication" -name "defaultLogonDomain" -value "CMC"

Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location 'PackageManager' -filter "system.webServer/security/authentication/iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication/manyToOneMappings" -name "." -value @{name='My 1st Mapping';description='1st User Mapping';userName='DOMAIN\username';password='XXXXXXXXXXX'}

Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location 'PackageManager' -filter "system.webServer/security/authentication/iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication/manyToOneMappings/add[@name='My 1st Mapping']/rules" -name "." -value @{certificateField='Subject';certificateSubField='CN';matchCriteria='*.mydomain.com';compareCaseSensitive='False'}

Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location 'PackageManager' -filter "system.webServer/security/authentication/iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication/manyToOneMappings/add[@name='My 1st Mapping']/rules" -name "." -value @{certificateField='Issuer';certificateSubField='CN';matchCriteria='Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2';compareCaseSensitive='False'}
```

**What’s weird about all the above, is that I don’t see any references to this configuration in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config\applicationHost.config.**

When browsing this site, I get prompted to use a cert, but IE doesn't present the cert I was expecting:

[image]

That was a self-signed cert I had been experimenting with.

Then I get hit with a lovely 403, so I’m at an impasse.

What am I doing wrong in the config that it doesn't show up in applicationHost.config, and why am I not given a choice to present my client cert (it's in my store)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem under Windows Server 2012 and I solved it by adding two additional registry keys under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet \Control\SecurityProviders\Schannel`:

•   `ClientAuthTrustMode` Value type: `REG_DWORD`, Value data: `2`

•   `SendTrustedIssuerList` Value type: `REG_DWORD`, Value data: `0`

For more information see [IIS 8.5 - Mutual certificates authentication fails with error 403.16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27232340/iis-8-5-mutual-certificates-authentication-fails-with-error-403-16)

Answer (score 1):

Your GoDaddy certificate seems to be a Server Authentication certificate (Server authentication OID 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1) that can be used by IIS for SSL security and this one should be installed in Certificates>>Local computer>>Personal

For client certificates you need Client authentication OID 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2 and this one should be installed in Certificates>>Current User>>Personal.

[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LDED.png)